# Concatenate multiple rows of matrix into another matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, concatenation

I have a matrix which has a number of columns `M` and rows=`X*(2*L/M)` and I want to concatenate the rows of it to form another matrix of size `(X,2*L)`. This means that I take every `2*L/M` rows of the matrix and concatenate them into one row of the new matrix ,for example

```
A=
[12345;67890;12345;67890]

B=
[1234567890;1234567890]
```

Comment: I don't quite understand your example.  Do you wish to piece together multiple numbers to form a single number?  Will `A` or `B` contain floating point numbers?  What happens if we had `A = [1.23 3.45; 4.56 7.89]`?  What would be the result in `B` after the concatenation that you are seeking?  Your initial example is not enough to determine what we need to do and is over simplified.  Please provide one or a few more examples... preferably those that more complicated that truly demonstrate what you're really after.

Comment: It should probably be `A= [1 2 3 4 5...]` ?

Comment: @articuno: Please don't edit questions in such a way, you don't know if the changed example matches QAs intention.

Comment: @Daniel - I've rolled back the changes.  The OP still hasn't responded to my question so until he/she does, I will leave the previous version of question remain here instead.

Comment: @articuno - I agree with Daniel.  Please do not assume what you believe the correction to the post is until the OP confirms.  I've asked the OP for clarification regarding this matter.  Editing with the assumption that you know what the OP is intending is very dangerous.  Always ask for clarification first, then when you feel confident, go ahead and modify.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work-

`B = reshape(A',2*L,X)';`